# Truncated normal

Tags: statistics

Assume $z$ is a normally distributed random variable $N(0,1)$. I have calculated the average value of $z>C$ when the distribution is truncated at $z=c$. My answer is:

(avg z)= exp(-(cˆ2/2))/2Pi/p(z>c)

where $p(z>c)$ is the area of the tail above $c$.

Thak you for indicating if that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The expected value of a truncated from below normal random variable $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, is

$$E(X\mid X>c) = \mu +\sigma\frac{\phi(c)}{1-\Phi(c)}$$

where $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are the standard normal probability density and cumulative distribution functions respectively. In your case, $\mu =0, \;\; \sigma=1$, so

$$E(X\mid X>c) = \frac{\phi(c)}{1-\Phi(c)} = \frac {\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-\frac 12 c^2}}{P(X>c)}$$

Is this what you arrived at? (due to not using MathJax, the result you state in the question is unclear).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I did arrive at the same result but there was a typo in my question: I forgot to include the square root symbol over 2 x Pi.

Comment: You're welcome.